# Updating a clockpicker input field using XML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml, error-handling

```js
 document.getElementById("clockTimerID")[count].innerHTML = "3:30";
```

```html
<div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-0 col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-0 col-xs-5 col-xs-offset-0">
    <span class="small">Start Time</span>
    <div class="input-group clockpicker start" data-donetext="Done">
       <input class="input-sm form-control" type="text" id="clockTimerID" name="clockTimerNAME" value="12:00"/>
       <span class="hidden-xs input-group-addon"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"> </span></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am attempting to update the input field via XML. The input field is normally controlled by a plugin called clockpicker. (https://github.com/weareoutman/clockpicker) I have attempted to reference the field by id with no luck.

When I attempt to reference by ID I get the following error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of undefined

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
document.getElementById("clockTimerID").value = "3:30";
```

Answer (score 0):

## Hello!

```
document.getElementById("clockTimerID")[count].innerHTML = "3:30";
```

getElementById returns single element, because ID should be unique and thus it isn't an array.

remove **[count]** from this line and check if it will work.

Comment: no longer getting the error message however no update is performed.